# fgets não funciona

Tags: c, criptografia

Estou desenvolvendo um código para criptografar na cifra de cesar. A descriptografia está funcionando perfeitamente, porém para criptografar, o `fgets` não espera eu digitar o texto. Já tentei de tudo, o único comando que funciona é o: scanf("%s", &cifra), mas este comando só lê uma palavra e eu preciso ler um texto.

(o `fgets` com problema esta apontado com uma seta "--->").

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void menu (void);
void cript(void);
void descript (void);


int numero;
char cifra[50];
int i,tam;
FILE *arq1,*arq2;

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 1;
}

void menu (void)
{
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n     Critografia utilizando Cifra de Cesar\n\n");
        printf("     1-Critografar Texto\n");
        printf("     2-Descriptografar mensagem\n");
        printf("     3-Sair\n\n");
        printf("     Escolha a opcao desejada: ");
        scanf("%d", &numero);

        switch(numero)
        {
            case 1: 
                cript();
            break;

            case 2:
                descript();
            break;

            case 3:
                system("cls");
                printf("\n\n     Saindo...\n\n");
                system("pause");
                exit(0);
            break;

            default:
                printf("Opcao Invalida!");
            break;

        }

    }while(numero!=3);
}

void cript (void)
{
    int numero;
    char cifra[50];
    int i,tam;
    FILE *arq1,*arq2;

    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n     Informe o texto: ");
    **--->fgets(cifra,50,stdin);**

    tam = strlen(cifra);

    arq1 = fopen("cript.txt","w");

    for(i=0; i<tam; i++)
    {
        if(cifra[i] == 'z')
        {
            cifra[i] = 'c';
            putc(cifra[i],arq1);
        }
        else
            if(cifra[i] == 'y')
            {
                cifra[i] = 'b';
                putc(cifra[i],arq1);
            }
            else
                if(cifra[i] == 'x')
                {
                    cifra[i] = 'a';
                    putc(cifra[i],arq1);
                }
                else
                    if(cifra[i] == 'Z')
                    {
                        cifra[i] = 'C';
                        putc(cifra[i],arq1);
                    }
                    else
                        if(cifra[i] == 'Y')
                        {
                            cifra[i] = 'B';
                            putc(cifra[i],arq1);
                        }
                        else
                            if(cifra[i] == 'X')
                            {
                                cifra[i] = 'A';
                                putc(cifra[i],arq1);
                            }
                            else
                                if(cifra[i] == ' ' || cifra[i] == '\n')
                                    putc(cifra[i],arq1);
                                else
                                    putc(cifra[i] +3,arq1);
    } 
    fclose(arq1);
}



void descript (void)
{
    int numero;
    char cifra[50];
    int a,tam;
    FILE *arq1,*arq2;

    system("cls");
    arq1 = fopen("cript.txt","r");
    fgets(cifra,50,arq1);

    tam = strlen(cifra);

    arq2 = fopen("descript.txt","w");

    for(a=0; a<tam; a++)
    {
        if(cifra[a] == 'c')
        {
            cifra[a] = 'z';
            putc(cifra[a],arq2);
        }
        else
            if(cifra[a] == 'b')
            {
                cifra[a] = 'y';
                putc(cifra[a],arq2);
            }
            else
                if(cifra[a] == 'a')
                {
                    cifra[a] = 'x';
                    putc(cifra[a],arq2);
                }
                else
                    if(cifra[a] == 'C')
                    {
                        cifra[a] = 'Z';
                        putc(cifra[a],arq2);
                    }
                    else
                        if(cifra[a] == 'B')
                        {
                            cifra[a] = 'Y';
                            putc(cifra[a],arq2);
                        }
                        else
                            if(cifra[a] == 'A')
                            {
                                cifra[a] = 'X';
                                putc(cifra[a],arq2);
                            }
                            else
                                if(cifra[a] == ' ' || cifra[a] == '\n')
                                    putc(cifra[a],arq2);
                                else
                                    putc(cifra[a] -3,arq2);
    } 
        fclose(arq2);
}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema? Seja mais específico.

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona um getchar() para ler o Enter do teclado.

```
    ...
    printf("     Escolha a opcao desejada: ");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    getchar();

    switch(numero)
    {
        case 1:
    ...
```

Comment: Valeu cara, era exatamente o que precisava.

Answer (score -3):

Pode ser alguma coisa travada na memória, tente utilizar o comando "fflush(stdin)" antes de utilizar o comando fgets.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` tem comportamento indefinido e não é garantido que funcione sempre, em todo lugar, para qualquer ambiente (veja mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979209), [aqui](/a/165142/112052) e - por que não? - [aqui](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/) :-D)